# Compiling dlib on OS X

Tags: dlib

I try to use dlib in Qt project on OS X. So, in this try I did following:

In dlib root:

```
cd examples
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Release
```

In dlib root:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/user/dlib_build
cmake --build . --config Release --target install
```

.pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /Users/user/dlib_build/include
LIBS += -L/Users/user/dlib_build/lib
LIBS += -ldlib
```

main.cpp:

```
//...
frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector();
//...
```

Compile output:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_dgesvd_", referenced from:
       dlib::lapack::binding::gesvd(char, char, int, int, double*, int, double*, double*, int, double*, int, double*, int) in main.o 
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

How can I solve this and use dlib with Qt on OS X?

Comment: Probably not useful at this point time, but I've recently bumped into the same error and using `otool -L` on dlib pointed that the LAPACK library it uses comes from `libBLAS.dylib` and `ibLAPACK.dylib` part of the `Accelerate` framework on OSX. As long as your also link against this framework, the project should compile.

Comment: Adding Accelerate framework works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right solution is to add missing libraries for linking. When Dlib was build - it found some BLAS library and enabled BLAS support.
To find this library - take a look at pkgconfig file from dlib that is located at 
/Users/user/dlib_build/lib/pkgconfig, it will have line like "Libs: -L${libdir} -ldlib"
Qt does not manage such dependencies automatically, so you should add blas libraries by hand

The other (simple) solution is to build dlib without BLAS/LAPACK support:
In dlib root:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DDLIB_USE_BLAS=OFF -DDLIB_USE_LAPACK=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/user/dlib_build
cmake --build . --config Release --target install
```

Answer (score 0):

add framework accelerate is fine

if you use cmake, add:

```
target_link_libraries(your_app "-framework accelerate")
```

if you use xcode, add accelerate directly.